# Fetching old session value even if session is destroyed

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

```
 @Override
   public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0)
   {
      boolean isRemoved = sessionIdSet.remove(arg0.getSession().getId());
      if (isRemoved)
      {
          arg0.getSession().invalidate();
          System.out.println(arg0.getSession().getAttribute("userName"));
          System.out.println("session destroyed");
      }
   }
```

Suppose the attribute **`userName`** was **`testUser`** at the time of login. So after timeout in my java console I get **`null and session destroyed`** printed. So if it is null that means when I do following in my **`jsp`** I should get **`null`** but instead still I get **`testUser`**

```
 $("body").click(function(event){
            var property="<%=session.getAttribute("userName")%>";
            //Here I expect property to be null as session is destroyed 
                //and it prints null in java so it should also here.
            alert(property);
            //But what i get here is testUser
    }
```

**Using Spring interceptor**

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {

        boolean allowRequest = true;
        String requestUri = request.getRequestURI().toString();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        logger.info("Pre-intercepting request URI: " + requestUri);
        try {
        if(null != session) {
            String sessionBelongsTo = (String) session.getAttribute("CUR_TYPE");
            String user = (String) session.getAttribute("userName");
            System.out.println(user);

            if(!requestUri.endsWith("/login") && !requestUri.endsWith("/loginauth") && !requestUri.endsWith("sap-ui-core.js") && !requestUri.endsWith("/main")) {
                    if(null == user) {
                        logger.info(""
                                + "Login required, redirecting to LOGIN page");
                          response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
                          allowRequest = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        logger.info("Login not required");
                        }
                }
            }
        else{
            logger.debug("session is null.redirecting to login");
            session = request.getSession();
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
            allowRequest = false;
        }
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
            logger.info(ioe.getMessage());
            allowRequest = false;
        }
          return allowRequest;
        }
```

Using interceptor makes an redirect call `GET http://localhost:9090/app/login` which is successfull but redirect never really happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different codes. You have to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

I.e. `<%=session.getAttribute("userName")%>` is processed on the server, and your browser receives e.g. `var property="johndoe";` - the JSP code is **NOT** executed again when your `onclick` handler is executed.

Comment: so in that case I want to redirect my page to login page upon timeout so HttpServletResponse would not work in sessionDestroyed method so I cant do response.sendRedirect from there and I cannot get latest value from session in jsp too so is there any alternative to acheive that

Comment: Google for `ajax session timeout`.